# Chartist: remove all grid lines but display axis

Tags: javascript, svg, chartist.js

I know there is an option to remove gridlines: `showGrid: false`. But that will remove all grid lines including main axes.

**Is there a way to remove all gridlines except main axis like this?**
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to achieve that with pure css:

```css
.ct-vertical ~ .ct-vertical {
    stroke: none;
}
.ct-horizontal ~ .ct-horizontal {
    stroke: none;
}
```